# Как сделать зажатие кнопки на HTML5 и JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, button

Как сделать зажатие кнопки на HTML5 и JavaScript (когда долго держишь кнопку  и например постоянно изменяет положение блока)

Comment: Использовать события `onkeydown` и `onkeyup`.

Comment: Спасибо вам а то я просто начинающий Веб-разработчик хочу сделать что-то наподобие игры и вот это нужно было. И ещё раз огромнейшее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант на JS, подробное описание в комментариях к  коду.

```js
let clamped = document.querySelector('#clamped'),
    elPress = false, // "флаг" в котором будем хранить какая кнопка зажата
    pressTimer; // Тут будет храниться таймер "зажатого" действия

clamped.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) { // Вешаем обработчик когда НАЖИМАЕМ кнопку мыши, на нужный элемент
  if(e.button === 0) { // Запускаем если это кнопка ЛКМ
    elPress = e.target; // Запишем текущю кнопку в переменную
    pressTimer = setInterval(function() { // Запускаем таймер
      document.querySelector('.random-color').style.background = '#'+RandomHEX(); // Я для примера буду меня фон блока на рандомный
    }, 100); // Скорость определите сами
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) { // Вешаем обработчик на документ, по отжатию ЛКМ
  if(e.target === elPress || // Если нажатый элемент === нашему зажатому
  elPress !== false // ИЛИ зажатый элемент НЕ false
  && e.button === 0) { // И нажатая кнопка === ЛКМ
    clearInterval(pressTimer); // То остановим таймер
    elPress = false; // И поменяем флаг на false
  }
}, true);


function RandomHEX() {
    return (Math.random() * 0x1000000 | 0x1000000).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```

```css
#clamped:active {
  border-color: blue;
}

.random-color {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #666;
}
```

```html
<button id="clamped">Зажми меня</button>

<div class="random-color"></div>
```

Comment: Если зажать и увести указатель за пределы кнопки, не отпускает

Comment: @DiD, да, заметил, спасибо, уже переписал)

Comment: тут на mouseup надо просто чистить таймер без проверок, elpress какой-то огромный костыль) и тогда уж добавить эту логику и на mouseleave за document

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, не совсем понял, типо `document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', e => clearInterval();)` и всё? Если так, то можно и так, но "глянул в один из вариантов событий", когда после "отжатия" будет ещё какая-нибудь функция, а с данным примером зачем её выполнять каждый раз после отжатия, даже не зажимаемой кнопки.

Comment: @De.Minov да, так. Пустой таймер быстрее очистится, чем проверятся условия, ну и потом иногда не так критичны лишние операции по сравнению с костылями. Если нужно условие дальше – можно смотреть запущен ли интервал

Comment: Спасибо вам а то я просто начинающий Веб-разработчик хочу сделать что-то наподобие игры и вот это нужно было. И ещё раз огромнейшее спасибо.

Comment: @ДаниилГаврин, не за что, удачи в начинаниях. Если мой ответ помог, отметьте его как правильный (левый-верхний угол ответа, под рейтингом)

Comment: @ДаниилГаврин для игры лучше будет использовать не setInterval, а requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: @De.Minov Спасибо Денис! (+) Ответ полезен для меня.